# Exception pointer call

Tags: c++, pointers

```
struct A {
    bool testA(int) { 
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
        return true; 
    };
};
struct B {
    void testB() {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    };
};

int main() {
    A a;
    ((B*)(&a))->testB();
    return 0;
}
```

Why can a member function of a B-class object be called with a pointer to an A-class object without throwing an exception？

Comment: What you do here is undefined behaviour, *anything* might happen, including your programme running as expected, showing strange behaviour or crashing, the latter two possibly at a seemingly entirely unrelated location/point of time.

Comment: In this (un-?)lucky case you get a programme seemingly running fine due a few facts: 1.: On calling member functions the address of the object you call the former on is provided as implicit argument; as these addresses (on your platform) do not differ, there's no problem with; 2.: You do not access any (incompatible) members of the object either, 3. you do not provide non-matching arguments as the signatures involved do not differ in these.

Comment: Can you explain to us WHAT your are trying to do? Know that code that compile is NOT necessarily correct code. And C++ compilers assume you know what you are doing, even if you dont. (And in this case to be honest it seems very much like you are trying to break the compiler on purpose)

Comment: There is no rule in C++ that says bugged programs must throw exceptions (or print error messages, or crash, or anything else...). Your program has a bug but you are expecting it to behave one particular way, the expectation is wrong.

Comment: Everything here (examples) probably compiles: [Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) but produces an invalid program.  C++ should come with a health warning.

Comment: Also, `void` as return type for `main` is not allowed. It _must_ always be declared as `int`. There are some compilers which accept `void`, but they shouldn't (without a diagnostic) according to the C++ standard.

Comment: And you are missing `;` after each `struct` definition. These are not optional either and without them the program is ill-formed as well. The compiler should also refuse this. (And there is an obvious typo: `mian` -> `main`).

Comment: "Why ... without throwing exception ?" The C++ language does not throw exceptions at you. Other languages do that, but not C++. You could write code to make it throw an exception for the wrong pointer type, but thats not on the language level, its your code

Comment: @molbdnilo: dynaimc_cast of a reference type can throw std::bad_cast, right?

Comment: @user17732522 *must* this is not true, implementations are allowed to accept other signatures of `main`, diagnostic is not required.

Comment: *Why can a member function of a B-class object be called with a pointer to an A-class object without throwing an exception?*  Where in your code are you throwing an exception?  Where in your code are you detecting that this situation and handling it by throwing an exception? When you use a **cast** you are telling the compiler "Shut up, I know what I'm doing", but this appears not to be the case. Don't use casts.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#2.sentence-2: "_shall have a declared return type of type int_". Only the rest of the function type is implementation-defined. (Also, for a function the return type is not part of the signature: https://eel.is/c++draft/defns.signature)

Comment: @user17732522 Indeed, I probably confused it with how main is defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ core language does not use exceptions to signal that the programmer has written code that breaks a language rule, except in very specific cases where the violation is detectable without run-time overhead, such as `std::bad_new_array_length`.

Instead, the usual approach is "undefined behaviour". The implementation usually cannot be expected to check whether you are following the rules, because doing so would make the code slower. For example, in the case of a member function call, one strategy to catch bugs like what is shown by the OP would be to allocate a vptr and RTTI information for *every* object, not only objects with polymorphic types. Then, *every* member function call, at runtime, could look up the type info and compare it with the statically required type (in this case, `B`). Notice that this implementation strategy would increase the size of every object, increase the size of every executable image (due to the generation of RTTI information), and increase the amount of time taken for each member function call. In other words, it would significantly worsen the performance of the program even if the program is correct. So, instead of mandating this kind of pessimization, the C++ standard just lets implementations compile member function calls under the assumption that the object expression really denotes an object of appropriate type. If you violate this rule, you get what you get.

(Some implementations use this freedom to perform aggressive "time travel" optimizations, but I won't get into that here.)